# Why is None represented as null?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

[`CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370528.aspx) can be used to

> Permit the use of null as a representation for nullary discriminators in a discriminated union

`Option.None` is the most prominent example of this.

Why is this useful? How is a null check better than the traditional mechanism for checking union cases (the generated `Tag` property)?

It leads to perhaps unexpected behavior:

```ml
Some(1).ToString() //"Some(1)"
None.ToString()    //NullReferenceException
```

#### EDIT

I tested Jack's assertion that comparing to null instead of a static readonly field is faster.

```ml
[<CompilationRepresentation(CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue)>]
type T<'T> =
  | Z
  | X of 'T

let t = Z
```

Using ILSpy, I can see `t` compiles to null (as expected):

```cs
public static Test.T<a> t<a>()
{
    return null;
}
```

The test:

```ml
let mutable i = 0
for _ in 1 .. 10000000 do
  match t with
  | Z -> i <- i + 1
  | _ -> ()
```

The results:

> Real: 00:00:00.036, CPU: 00:00:00.046, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

If the `CompilationRepresentation` attribute is removed, `t` becomes a static readonly field:

```cs
public static Test.T<a> t<a>()
{
    return Test.T<a>.Z;
}

public static Test.T<T> Z
{
    [CompilationMapping(SourceConstructFlags.UnionCase, 0)]
    get
    {
        return Test.T<T>._unique_Z;
    }
}

internal static readonly Test.T<T> _unique_Z = new Test.T<T>._Z();
```

And the results are the same:

> Real: 00:00:00.036, CPU: 00:00:00.031, GC gen0: 0, gen1: 0, gen2: 0

The pattern match is compiled as `t == null` in the former case and `t is Z` in the latter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jack's answer seems good, but to expand a little bit, at the IL level the CLR provides a specific opcode for loading null values (`ldnull`) and efficient means of testing for them (`ldnull` followed by `beq`/`bne.un`/`ceq`/`cgt.un`).  When JITted, these should be more efficient than dereferencing a `Tag` property and branching accordingly.  While the per-call savings are probably small, option types are used frequently enough that the cumulative savings may be significant.

Of course, as you note there is a tradeoff: methods inherited from `obj` may throw null reference exceptions.  This is one good reason to use `string x`/`hash x`/`x=y` instead of `x.ToString()`/`x.GetHashCode()`/`x.Equals(y)` when dealing with F# values.  Sadly, there is no (possible) equivalent of `x.GetType()` for values represented by `null`.

Comment: It seems to use a type test (`is`) instead of checking `Tag`, which appears to be as fast as a null check.

Comment: Type tests aren't as fast as null checks in general (though they may be in some cases).  Also, their performance may have been different in the .NET 2.0 days, when F# was originally implemented.

Comment: If that's true (I'd love to have proof) then this seems to go the farthest toward explaining it.

Comment: Daniel, just think of it this way: what underlying CPU instructions need to be emitted (by the JIT compiler) then executed at run-time for null checks and type tests. Null checks can be compiled to a single CPU instruction, a type test is almost always going to be more than that since it'll need to call into the CLR to perform the type test. Even if they did some really advanced optimizations, it's still going to require more than one CPU instruction.

Comment: @daniel, I know this is years ago, but type tests are used when the number of cases is 4 or less, `Tag` is used for 5 or more. This threshold was defined after numerous performance tests back in 2005, but is still there, see discussion in this PR: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/pull/762. Also, the IL for null checks is now better optimized, the performance difference may be easier to see.

Comment: @Abel Very interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The F# compiler sometimes uses `null` as a representation for None because it's more efficient than actually creating an instance of FSharpOption<'T> and checking the `Tag` property.

Think about it -- if you have a normal F# type (like a record) that's not allowed to be null, then any pointer to an instance of that type (the pointer used internally by the CLR) will never be `NULL`. At the same time, if `T` is a type which can represent `n` states, then `T option` can represent `n+1` states. So, using `null` as a representation for None simply takes advantage of that one extra state value which is available by the fact that F# types aren't allow to be null.

If you want to try turning this behavior off (for normal F# types), you can apply `[<AllowNullLiteral(true)>]` to them.

Comment: How is this better than representing nullary cases as static readonly fields, like `String.Empty`?

Comment: Nullary cases in union types *are* generally compiled as static readonly fields. Using `null` to represent `None` is a specific optimization for the `'T option` type, since it's just quite often and the CLR can generate slightly more efficient code this way.

Comment: `[<AllowNullLiteral>]` allows you to assign `null` to some variable typed with some standard (i.e., non-nullable) F# type, like a record. If you apply that attribute to an F# type (record, union, class, etc.) then write some code which uses an `'T option` version of that type, you'll see that the compiler uses the static readonly field version of None (FSharpOption.None).

Comment: That seems to contradict your assertion that it is more efficient than new'ing up instances of `FSharpOption<'T>`, since that would be unnecessary for a nullary field.

Comment: Applying [<AllowNullLiteral>] to your types would result in less efficient code. And yes, it is a small optimization, but as often as 'T option is used it's probably a measurable (although small) performance gain.

Comment: I'm not able to verify your claims. See the update to my question.

Comment: On second thought, the speed should be the about the same -- the CLR should be able to optimize the test against the static readonly field because it's location in memory will be constant (so the address can be hardcoded into the machine-code instructions emitted by the JIT compiler).

Comment: Not quite -- calling the 'Tag' property may still require an indirect memory access, which would be slower than if the CLR could just emit a direct comparison instruction.

Comment: It doesn't check `Tag`. It uses a type test.