# Can I put let statements in an F# list comprehension?

Tags: f#

I am trying to write a list comprehension in F# and can't get it to compile:

```
[for x in xs do
    let y = f(x)
    when g(y) -> y]
```

Is there any way to save an intermediate computation in the middle of a list comprehension?  How can I rework this list comprehension so that it compiles?

Comment: A "list comprehension" usually has [ at the start and ] at the end.

Comment: BTW, `when` is only for additional conditions in pattern matching (and more advanced: for type constraints).

Comment: I added in the square brackets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just skip the list comprehension.

```
let ys = xs |> List.map f |> List.filter g
```

However it is simple enough to get your code working.

```
let ys = [ for x in xs do
               let y = f(x)
               if g(y) then yield y ]
```

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @ChaosPandion's solution, you could also write this using `List.choose` -- think of it as a combination of `List.map` and `List.filter` which avoids creating an extra list (i.e., instead of creating a list with `List.map` just to pass it to `List.filter`).

```
let ys =
    xs
    |> List.choose (fun x ->
        let y = f x
        if g y then Some y else None)
```

Comment: Honestly I was taking a look at the implementation and I believe using this will lead to a bit more object creation. The reason being the choose implementation actually calls List.rev after building up the list.

Comment: @ChaosPandion Could you elaborate on what you mean by "a bit more object creation"?  I don't understand.

Comment: @mushroom - What I mean is that for a given input `Data` this version will create `X` objects while my version will create `Y` objects where `X` is greater than `Y` by at least `N`. My "theorem" kind of breaks down as the length of the input data approaches zero but we can't all be expert mathematicians now can we?

Comment: @ChaosPandion Your first version creates more objects than if you were to use `List.choose`; your second version is basically `List.choose` written as a list comprehension, so it should create the same number of objects (more or less).

Comment: @JackP - Well you can't forget that the Option type is a class so that allocation counts as well. My thought was that with the build-up of the choose list and the reversal of said list the overall object creation would be pretty close on average. This of course all depends on how often `g` returns `false`. I suppose I was thinking in asymptotic terms where the best case for choose is when `g` will often return `false` and the best case for my first example is when `g` rarely returns false.

Comment: @ChaosPandion `Option` is a class, but in many (most?) cases when the parameter type is a reference type (e.g., a `string`) the F# compiler optimizes away the `Option` altogether by using `null` instead of None. There was an earlier discussion about this optimization here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959321/why-is-none-represented-as-null/11959583