# Why Array.zeroCreate still fills null for non nullable type?

Tags: f#

Does it imply that whenever I am passed an array of a non nullable type, I should still check if it is null? Actually it is not even possible to check `<> null` but have to use `operator.unchecked` .How is it better than C#?

```
type test=
    {
        value: int
    }

let solution = Array.zeroCreate 10

solution.[0] <- {value = 1}
solution.[1].value   // System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

type test =
  {value: int;}
val solution : test [] =
  [|{value = 1;}; null; null; null; null; null; null; null; null; null|]
val it : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where the array is being passed from.

If the array is created and used only within F#, then no, you don't need to check for null; in fact, you *shouldn't* check for null (using `Unchecked.defaultOf`) because the F# compiler optimizes some special values like `[]` (and `None`, in certain cases) by representing them as `null` in the compiled IL.

If you're consuming an array being passed in by code written in another language (such as C#), then yes, you should still check for null. If the calling code just creates the array and doesn't mutate it any further, then you'll only need to perform the null checks once.

EDIT : Here's a previous discussion about how the F# compiler optimizes the representation of certain values using `null`: [Why is None represented as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959321/why-is-none-represented-as-null/11959583)

Comment: Even if i use only within F#, e.g. solution.[1].value would raise System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: You're the one calling Array.zeroCreate. So populate the array before you expose it to other code that might get a NullReferenceException, and it's not an issue.

Answer (score 2):

As the documentation for `Array.zeroCreate` indicates, it initializes the elements to `Unchecked.defaultof<_>`.  This therefore carries with it all of the same caveats that direct use of `Unchecked.defaultof` does.  Generally, my advice would be to use `Array.create`/`Array.init` whenever possible, and to treat  `Array.zeroCreate` as a possible performance optimization (requiring care whenever dealing with non-nullable types).

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a record type, which is implemented as a class, which is indeed nullable.  If you intended to create a struct, your code should look something like this:

```
type test =
    struct
        val value: int
        new(v) = { value = v }
        override x.ToString() = x.value.ToString()
    end

let solution = Array.zeroCreate 10

solution.[0] <- test(1)
```

This outputs: `val solution : test [] = [|1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0|]`

You could also write the type using the Struct attribute, saving you a level of indentation.

```
[<Struct>]
type test =
    val value: int
    new(v) = { value = v }
    override x.ToString() = x.value.ToString()
```