# How to upcast to an option type?

Tags: f#

How do I create `some string` from a string?

I'm going through the [F# Koans tutorials](https://github.com/ChrisMarinos/FSharpKoans), and am I stuck on this one:

```
[<Koan>]
let ProjectingValuesFromOptionTypes() =
    let chronoTrigger = { Name = "Chrono Trigger"; Platform = "SNES"; Score = Some 5 }
    let halo = { Name = "Halo"; Platform = "Xbox"; Score = None }

    let decideOn game =

        game.Score
        |> Option.map (fun score -> if score > 3 then "play it" else "don't play")

    //HINT: look at the return type of the decide on function
    AssertEquality (decideOn chronoTrigger) (Some "play it")
    AssertEquality (decideOn halo) (Some "don't play")
```

the exception i get is:

```
You have not yet reached enlightenment ...
  Expected: null
  But was:  <Some(don't play)>
```

How do I upcast a string to be of type `option string`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I upcast a string to be of type option string?

Casting has a very specific meaning. What you want to do is wrap your `string` with an `Option`, not cast it. To do this, use the `Some` constructor function:

```
let x = Some myString //x: string option
```

However, I don't think that is going to fix assertion error you're getting (at least, not by itself). I don't want to give you the complete answer here (especially since that's not what you're asking and finding the answer is the entire point of doing a Koan) but I will leave this clue as to why you're seeing a `null` in the assertion:

```
None |> printfn "Value: %A" // Value: <null>
```

See [Why is None represented as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959321/why-is-none-represented-as-null) for some more information on that behavior.